# Is it possible to run Alea GPU on MacBook Pro in Virtual Machine

Tags: macos, virtualization, parallels, vmware-fusion, aleagpu

I just watched the Daniel Egloff interview on Channel9 and noticed he was using a MacBook Pro.
https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Seth-Juarez/Radically-Simplified-GPU-Programming-with-C

Is it possible to run Alea GPU inside a Parallels or VMWare VM on a MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. The GPU in a Mac BookPro does not allow GPU virtualization.

GPU virtualization requires two things:

1. a GPU that supports GPU pass through. Only specific GPUs support the [NVIDIA GPU virtualization tech](http://www.nvidia.com/object/grid-technology.html), these are the NVIDIA M40, the K80 available in Azure or the older K1, K2 Grid or the K520 in AWS.
2. a hypervisor that can handle GPU pass through, such as Xen or vSphere or the new Hyper-V on Windows 2016 Server